# Preventing console errors

Tags: javascript, console

Whats the best approach for preventing errors when console.log calls have been left in JavaScript and it is executed on Browsers without a console or with console deactivated. Is there a way it can be automatically overridden to become a javascript alert for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!window.console) console = {log: function(s) {alert(s);}};
```

You can of course add more of the functions that console normally has.

Comment: A more complete version is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265684/using-console-log-with-firebug-ok-locally-not-when-published-to-my-live-site/3265752#3265752)

Comment: Note that the expression `if(!console)` will produce a `ReferenceError` if the `console` identifier hasn't been declared. That's why using the `typeof` operator, or checking `if (!window.console)` is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if the `console` identifier is available, you can do it either by using the `typeof` operator, or by checking `window.console`, because if you access directly an identifier and it's not defined, you will get a ReferenceError.

For example:

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
  window.console = {
    log: function () {
      // do nothing
    }
  };
  console.warn = console.debug = console.log;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use :-

```
if(typeof(console) != "undefined")
```

Comment: doesnt work if you've got console calls all through your code tho

Comment: There's no need for parentheses around the `console`: `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @snaken - True, you'd have to add the check to each, not as simple as @sje397's solution.

Comment: @Tim - no need, just a preference.