# javascript: console.log not working in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function( $ ){ $.fn.openlayers = function( mapElementId, options ) {
        alert(console.log);
        console.log(options);
        ...
    }
});
```

Im trying to extend functionality in a javascript library, but much to my suprise, when i got started i realized that nothing was being logged by `console.log`.. I know that the code is being executed due to the `alert()` firing properly. However the returned response from the alert function seems to be `"function(){}"`, is that correct? or is in fact console.log and empty function?

So any clues on what's going on here, and why console.log isn't working?

---

I think i might have found the culprit. Im working with a OpenLayers javascript file, and i can see that their library sets

```
OpenLayers.Console={log:function(){},...
```

However, this is uppercase Console, but maybe that doesn't make a difference? I also have to be in the OpenLayers scope, which i can't really see that i am. So i'm still a little baffled. But it would explain why i'm seeing an empty function

---

This is the output i get from typing "console" in the debug window of chrome after loading the application where this error occurs.

```
assert: function (){}
count: function (){}
debug: function (){}
dir: function (){}
dirxml: function (){}
error: function (){}
group: function (){}
groupEnd: function (){}
info: function (){}
log: function (){}
profile: function (){}
profileEnd: function (){}
time: function (){}
timeEnd: function (){}
trace: function (){}
warn: function (){}
__proto__: Object
```

So it would seem that something, possibly the openlayers javascript is overriding the native console.

Comment: Could it be that you're out of scope to reach `console`? Have you tried `window.console.log`?

Comment: `console.log` is not an empty function. What browser are you using?

Comment: Both, chrome and firefox returns an empty function in the alert() response. window.console.log, returns the same response aswell...

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3265684/338803

Comment: @JoakimJohansson - if there's no `console` in the current scope wouldn't the JS engine look in the next containing scope and so forth up through to `window`?

Comment: Thats why closures should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line *before* OpenLayer script to tell it not to override the console functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.firebug=true;
</script>
```

Comment: Well, not me personally, but someone else working on this project might have. so this very well might be the case. Ill look into it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 2):

Just click on ALL, you will definitely see the  console.log output.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/peduZ.png]

Hope it helps...!!!