# console.log not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my JavaScript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
  jQuery('body').click( function() {
    console.log( 'test console' );
    alert( 'test alert' );
  });
});
```

I have got alert showing but the 'test console' won't print in the console either in chrome or firefox. I have no idea why. Anybody met this before?

**EDIT**
I found out what the issue was. It turns out this was Magento 1.5 specific issue. Before the document was "ready", the js/varien/js.js script run and it was disabling the default console. It was in deed very confusing and I'm glad Magento dropped this in future releases (at least it's commented out in Magento 1.7).

Comment: Not really, works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dA3hH/.

Comment: Are you sure you know how to look at the console ? Can you re-create the same at jsfiddle ?

Comment: Do you have another script on your page that defines a variable named console in the global scope?

Comment: Are you using OpenLayer? OpenLayer may hijack the console variable. <script type="text/javascript"> console.firebug=true; </script>

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write something like `(console = {}).log = function() {}`? )))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564110/javascript-console-log-not-working-in-this-context

Comment: This line helped however this is very strange because the jquery-1.6.min.js file is the only JavaScript file being called before this script. Thanks, @J Novack, I'll have a look at this OpenLayer, there should be something I'm missing here...

Comment: Thanks @dfsq, I'm pretty sure something like this is not being called before this script. The only file which is being called before that is jquery-1.6.min.js. And it obviously works fine in jsfiddle and anywhere else - only not on my page, that's why it is a very weird issue.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564110/javascript-console-log-not-working-in-this-context/20861058#20861058  ( worked for me )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using OpenLayer?  OpenLayer may hijack the console variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.firebug=true;
</script>
```

Comment: This line helped however this is very strange because the jquery-1.6.min.js file is the only JavaScript file being called before this script. Thanks, @J Novack, I'll have a look at this OpenLayer, there should be something I'm missing here...