# Console.log not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to log some data from my javascript code to check if its right, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Even when I type into the console:

```
console.log("hello");
```

the console just returns undefined (which is correct) but it also doesn't log the "hello".  If it matters, I'm using adblock and hoverzoom as my extensions.  Also, I'm on a macbook pro.  Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

Comment: have you tried killing the chrome process and restarting it?

Comment: @adeneo nice april fools

Comment: What platform? Because I can say that `console.log()` *definitely* works on my installation (Chrome 25 on Windows XP and Windows 7, and also in Chromium 24 on Ubuntu 12.10).

Comment: @mkoryak that worked!  do you know why this wouldve happened?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564110/javascript-console-log-not-working-in-this-context/20861058#20861058  ( worked for me )

Comment: Try running `delete console.log` in the console. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7089671/631764 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21954826/631764 ~~~ I don't see why this is closed or too localized. If this isn't helping anyone, why does it have 10,733 views and 7 upvotes for the question, and 8 for the answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515181/dynamically-inserted-script-tag-is-not-executed-in-the-correct-order

Comment: @ButtleButkus 's hint helped me

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most likely, you have some JavaScript in your code that overwrites `console.log` for compatibility reasons (this will also affect the console of the application's tab). You can verify that by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> *in this tab* and checking that `console.log` still works fine.

Comment: Right, for me it was the jsconsole.com's <script> tag that took control from the browser's console.

Comment: How do I undo this change in console.log, or get the same functionality another way??

Comment: I found out how to fix this in my case: `delete console.log`. See my comment to the question for more details.

Answer (score 9):

make sure 'Info' is checked in custom levels drop down. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with javascript 'alert()' and 'console.log()' apparently not working in Chrome, but working in Firefox..

I didn't find a complete solution online, so I hope this helps someone.

After a bit of a journey I discover that it is a caching issue. Chrome was not recognising updated script files. Clearing the cache ( 'Ctrl-Shft-Del' on Chrome ) got it working.

I'm on a Wordpress platform so I tried using the js file timestamp as the version parameter in 'wp_enqueue_script()' as an attempt to cache-bust.

eg.

```
    $ver = filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'my-file.js' );
```

this didn't work! .I think that the timestamp is too big and gets truncated? Whatever the timestamp was, the url of the js file '?ver=xxxxxxx' was identical.

A simpler version parameter, however, DOES change the url and Chrome reloads every time the version parameter is changed.

eg.

```
    $ver = '1.24';
```

Solution:

```
        $timestamp = filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'my-file.js' );
        $ver = date( 'His', $timestamp );
```

$ver Resolves to something like '104323' ie. 10:43 and 23 seconds
I reckon that should be unique enough!