# Dynamically inserted script tag is not executed in the correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is a snippet of my html code:

```
...

<script src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id="foo">
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        var jquery = document.createElement("script");
        jquery.src = ".../jquery.min.js";
        var self = document.getElementById("foo");
        self.parentNode.insertBefore(jquery, self.nextSibling);
        console.log("haha");
    }
</script>

<script>
    console.log("hehe");
</script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The first script tag is a jquery CDN.
The purpose of the script tag with id "foo" is that in case the CDN fails, it loads a local copy of jquery file before the following bootstrap js file is loaded.

However, somehow the inserted jquery file is not executed before the bootstrap js file. I tried putting `console.log("wow")` in that local jquery file. The result in console is `"haha", "hehe", some error message from bootstrap js file, "wow"`. Observing the DOM, the inserted jquery tag does appear before the `"hehe"` script, I am wondering why it's not executed in the right order and if there is a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `../jquery.min.js` instead of `.../jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamically inserted script files that are inserted with anything other than `document.write()` are not executed in ANY predictable order.  They are async and will load and run at their own pace.

You cannot depend upon any load order of async scripts relative to other scripts unless you write code to monitor when things have finished loading and only run code when some specific conditions have been met.

If you insert the script with `document.write()`, then it will become a blocking script load and it will load and run before any script tags parsed after the `document.write()` statement, the same as if the `<script>` tag was in the source of the page in that spot.  But, using `document.write()` potentially messes with some browser loading optimizations so there can be some downsides to using that technique.

You can use `document.write()` in this way:

```
<script src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="../jquery.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    }
</script>
```

A whole article on this topic: [CDNs fail, but your scripts don't have to - fallback from CDN to local jQuery](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So is there any better way to achieve my goal? i.e. to load a local jquery file in case CDN fails.

Comment: @Xufeng - If you need it to load conditionally and synchronously, then use `document.write()` to write the new `<script>` tag.

Comment: Or use a library like [LAB.js](http://labjs.com) that loads scripts in parallel asynchronously but lets you decide what needs to be executed synchronously.

Comment: @JuanMendes - let's see here.  In order to deal with a condition where the CDN is down, you're recommending that the OP include another script which can't be on a CDN (because this whole purpose is when the CDN isn't working) so it has to be a local script that is loaded special just to help solve this problem - but the whole point of using the CDN in the first place was to make things faster, but now you have to force loading of a new local script which won't make things faster.  I don't think this works out to be an advantage.  A couple lines of `document.write()` will solve this problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 Very true, I sometimes comment without taking a closer look at the actual question :)