# How do I force JavaScript to load in sequential order?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling with loading JS files in sequential order, despite having looked at various other SO posts and documentation on `async` and `defer`. My code structure is as follows:

```
<script src="lang.js"></script> <!--dynamically loads either eng.js or fra.js-->

<script src="task1.js"></script> <!--all of the task*.js depend on eng.js/fra.js-->
<script src="task2.js"></script>
<script src="task3.js"></script>
<script src="task4.js"></script>

<script>
   // inline JS; depends on all task*.js
</script>
```

The contents of `lang.js` are as follows:

```
let langScript = document.createElement("script")
// FR is a boolean defined earlier
langScript.setAttribute("src", FR ? "fra.js" : "eng.js"); 
langScript.setAttribute("async", "false");

let head = document.head;
head.insertBefore(langScript, head.firstElementChild);
```

By my understanding, these scripts should load and execute in the order `eng.js`/`fra.js` -> `task*.js` -> inline, but this doesn't seem to be the case (at least in Chrome and Firefox). How should I modify my code such that it executes in the correct order? (I would prefer not to use callbacks if possible as I don't want to change the individual JS files too much.)

Comment: This seems relevant: [Dynamically inserted script tag is not executed in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32515181/218196)

Comment: Appending scripts is ASYNCHRONOUS and there is not much you can do with it. You would be better off trying to do this in a different manner. We could give you better help if we knew what your code was actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Without using [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)

You *could* do something like the following:

- Remove the `<script>` elements for each of the `task*.js` files from the document
- Add an event listener for the `load` event of the inserted language script
- Create each of the `task*.js` scripts inside that event listener
- Add event listeners for the `load` event of each `task*.js` and use them to resolve a `Promise`, which is combined to form a global `Promise`
- Wait on that global `Promise` in the inline script.

Doing that, the relevant parts of `lang.js` would become:

```
const langScript = document.createElement('script');
langScript.setAttribute('src', FR ? 'fra.js' : 'eng.js');

const fullyLoaded = new Promise(resolve => {
  langScript.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const taskPromises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('src', `task${i}.js`);
      taskPromises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
        script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
      }));
      head.insertBefore(script, head.firstElementChild);
    }
    resolve(Promise.all(taskPromises));
  });
});

const head = document.head;
head.insertBefore(langScript, head.firstElementChild);
```

and the document would look something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="lang.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        await fullyLoaded;

        console.log('start of inline');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

None of the other scripts would need to be modified.

With this scheme:

- `lang.js` is loaded first
- `eng.js`/`fra.js` is completely loaded second
- `task1.js` through `task4.js` are completely loaded in any order
- inline scripts are run last

You will need to look at whether this manual deferral causes the loading to take to long; mocking this up locally has all the scripts loaded anywhere from 150ms to 450ms.

#### Using `import()`

Effectively the same as the above, but using the `import()` function-like keyword, `lang.js` becomes:

```
const src = FR ? './fra.js' : './eng.js';

const fullyLoaded = import(src).then(() => Promise.all([
  import('./task1.js'),
  import('./task2.js'),
  import('./task3.js'),
  import('./task4.js')
]));
```

There are some [differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) in how JavaScript code is run inside something that is `import`ed like this. The big ones are the imposition of strict mode, and the isolation of context, so you will most likely need to store any global variables explicitly onto the `window` variable, if you aren't already, for the `eng.js`, `fra.js` and `task*.js` files.